# How to pick starting parameters for MASS:fitdist() with the beta distribution?

Tags: r, beta-distribution, empirical-bayes

I have data set of ~700k yes/no events that I want to first aggregate on various features (e.g. group by average), always resulting in a 34 length vector.  From there, I want to fit a beta distribution to the resulting vector.  Below is an example of one possible vector:

```
dput(0.0955104277250779, 0.0782381918284555, 0.109683584625186, 
0.10115721657354, 0.102377369846524, 0.0691699604743083, 0.0940254652301665, 
0.078494747777906, 0.0824474231569216, 0.087598944591029, 0.114703196347032, 
0.0966910484151863, 0.0995783979120659, 0.090916800949877, 0.111081696404935, 
0.101724137931034, 0.0880689367194321, 0.106699751861042, 0.0772264084644516, 
0.109373466383118, 0.0732657833203429, 0.139175257731959, 0.0902068720589541, 
0.0900240916465903, 0.103787190855189, 0.0846888376687521, 0.0901782178217822, 
0.0943396226415094, 0.0778525161933234, 0.057852491291837, 0.0902365266227454, 
0.0940445474171976, 0.0834914611005693, 0.0886513916653852)
```

From there I want to fit a beta distribution (this is leading up to empiricial bayesian estimation btw).  See http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/ for the general idea.

When I try and fit a beta distribution however, I receive errors as shown below.

```
library(MASS)

m2 <- MASS::fitdistr(vector, densfun = "beta",  start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 10))

"Error in stats::optim(x = c(0.0955104277250779, 0.0782381918284555, 0.109683584625186,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]:"
```

Although I have been successful in fitting other vectors with the `fitdist()` function, I have been unable to fit this specific vector, although the data appears rational and well formed.  I have encountered a wide variety of errors when aggregating/subsetting the data in different ways as well.  In general, I'd like to be able to set the start parameters in such a way as to guarantee a fit, even if the resulting shape is less than ideal.  The goal being to remove the needed trial and error tweaking of the start values.

I've read the `fitdist` documentation thoroughly, and searched for a similiar question/issue with no luck.

Happy to provide additional example vectors as requested.

Comment: Have you tried different starting values, e.g., ones based on methods-of-moments estimates?  Otherwise, try changing the initial parameters to be non-integer valued, e.g., $(1.1, 10.1)$ instead of $(1,10)$.

Answer (score 8):

Using [`fitdistrplus`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html) works well in this case:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

x <- c(0.0955104277250779, 0.0782381918284555, 0.109683584625186, 
       0.10115721657354, 0.102377369846524, 0.0691699604743083,
       0.0940254652301665, 0.078494747777906, 0.0824474231569216,
       0.087598944591029, 0.114703196347032, 0.0966910484151863,
       0.0995783979120659, 0.090916800949877, 0.111081696404935,
       0.101724137931034, 0.0880689367194321, 0.106699751861042,
       0.0772264084644516, 0.109373466383118, 0.0732657833203429,
       0.139175257731959, 0.0902068720589541, 0.0900240916465903,
       0.103787190855189, 0.0846888376687521, 0.0901782178217822,
       0.0943396226415094, 0.0778525161933234, 0.057852491291837,
       0.0902365266227454, 0.0940445474171976, 0.0834914611005693,
       0.0886513916653852)

fit <- fitdist(x, "beta")

Fitting of the distribution ' beta ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
        estimate Std. Error
shape1  35.25746   8.511331
shape2 344.99152  83.815718

plot(fit, las = 1) # Checking fit
```

[image: GoodnessOfFit]

The function `fitdist` is able to chose "reasonable" starting values on its own, whereas `fitdistr` (MASS) struggles. We can get `fitdistr` to run without errors by supplying it reasonable starting values (but I'd recommend using the `fitdistr` package anyway):

```
library(MASS)

fitdistr(x, "beta", start = list(shape1 = 35, shape2 = 344))

    shape1      shape2  
   35.15658   343.98481 
 (  8.48699) ( 83.57280)
```

As @jbowman suggested in the comments, you can use the method-of-moments estimates as starting values. For the beta distribution, the [corresponding estimators are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Two_unknown_parameters):

\begin{align*}
\hat{\alpha} &= \bar{x}\left(\frac{\bar{x}(1 - \bar{x})}{s^2} - 1\right) \\
\hat{\beta} &= (1 - \bar{x})\left(\frac{\bar{x}(1 - \bar{x})}{s^2} - 1\right)
\end{align*}

Where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean and $s^2$ is the sample variance. In R:

```
beta_mom <- function(x) {

  m_x <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  s_x <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)

  alpha <- m_x*((m_x*(1 - m_x)/s_x^2) - 1)
  beta <- (1 - m_x)*((m_x*(1 - m_x)/s_x^2) - 1)

  return(list(alpha = alpha, beta = beta))

}

beta_mom(x)

$`alpha`
[1] 33.97962

$beta
[1] 332.4864
```

These are excellent starting values for the optimization algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment.  I noted that the fitdist() function still fails on many possible inputs for method = mle, but seems to work better with method = mge.  Im doing thorough testing and will update (and close if appropriate) this question shortly.

Comment: @LMico And what about the proposed method of estimating the parameters first with the method-of-moments and then supply those to fitdist?